# How do I limit redirects to only the site root and not child sites?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've got a site hosted by IIS with no site in the root, but two sites as subfolders. So `www.mysite.com` doesn't contain a site, but `www.mysite.com/new` does and so does `www.mysite.com/old`. I'm using IIS version 7.5.7600.16385.

I'm trying to set up a redirect in IIS so that when a user hits `www.mysite.com` they are redirected to `www.mysite.com/new`. The problem is when I navigate directly to `www.mysite.com/old` it appends /new so `www.mysite.com/old` becomes `www.mysite.com/old/new` which causes a 404.

I also tried adding `<remove name="system.webServer"/>` to the `web.config` in `/old` to prevent it from inheriting the redirect rule in the `/old` site. But it doesn't have any effect.

How do I limit the redirect so it only occurs when a user accesses `www.mysite.com` but not when they access `www.mysite.com/old` or `www.mysite.com/new`?

Answer (score 0):

A <httpRedirect> section added to your web.config is probably the easiest way to accomplish the desired redirection. The following Microsoft page should help.

[HTTP Redirects <redirection>](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)